# Remove a JMS message property

Tags: java, jms, tibco-ems

I am writing a Java batch which is listening messages from a queue (Oracle AQ) and sending them to another queue (Tibco EMS), where they are processed by a Tibco process (BW).

The problem is that the Oracle AQ driver automatically add some properties to messages (JMSXGroupID, JMSXGroupSeq) which cause errors when they are processed by Tibco process because they have bad values : JMSXGroupSeq should be an int but is set to null. Tibco falls into error when trying to parse message properties...

So I would like to remove only these 2 properties from all messages but it seems that the jms api only offers a clearProperties() method but no single property remove method (I'm using ths javax.jms.Message interface).

For now, I can see two solutions :

1. set a correct value to these 2 properties, as I'm assuming they will
   not be used further by Tibco
2. read all properties and reconstruct the messages without the 2 which cause problem. But this approach is very ugly...

Does anyone have any other solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to edit/clear some properties. We need to call clearProperties method as described [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596000685/message-properties/appc-4-fm2xml) to get write access :

*Once a message is produced (sent), its properties become read-only; the properties cannot be changed. While consumers can read the properties using the property accessor methods (getProperty( )), they cannot modify the properties using any of the mutator methods (setProperty( )). If the consumer attempts to set a property, the mutator method throws a javax.jms.MessageNotWriteableException.*

*Once a message is received, the only way its properties can be changed is by clearing out all the properties using the clearProperties( ) method. This removes all the properties from the message so that new ones can be added. Individual properties cannot be modified or removed once a message is sent.*

Comment: As an added note, the same situation applies to altering the message body itself after it is sent (`setText(...)`)...it cannot be set once the message is sent.  However, the way around this is to use `clearBody()`.  It appears that the `clearXxx()` methods  reset some sort of "writeable" type flag under the hood which then allows the possibility or writing again.

Comment: this is implemation specific and should be used carefully. for example if i am dealing with ByteMessage and using ActiveMQ as my underlying Queue, clear properties would work fine but it throws an exception while adding new property saying "message Body is read only" because ActiveMQ has extra check before adding property for ByteMessage. The same is not true when undelying queue is TIBCO Queue, here it would work fine

Answer (score 0):

There will be a function `public void removeProperty(String name)` in the concrete class implementation of javax.jms.Message interface. This classs is provider specific(Tibco EMS in your case). As it is closed source I cannot be for sure about the existence of that function. But it is present in HornetQ.It can be used to reset particular header property.

Other than that I thing option 1 is the best. You set it to some non null value acceptable by Message header parser of Tibco EMS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this solution but got a javax.jms.MessageNotWriteableException. I found that message header properties are protected and you need to call clearProperties() to get write access. Here are some explanations : [link](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596000685/message-properties/appc-4-fm2xml). So I had to take the second solution for now but we are waiting an answer from Oracle to solver the main problem of incorrect header value.